# Strange Powershell GCI Recurse Results with Wildcard

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, get-childitem

I'm trying to use GCI with the Recurse argument to get a list of all files WITHIN the subfolders of a specified path.

I'm using the following line:

```
gci 'C:\temp\TestRecurse\*\*' -Recurse
```

Underneath the TestRecurse folder, I have the following:

```
TestRecurse
 |---b.txt
 |---dir1
 |------a.txt
```

I expect a.txt to be returned. However, I'm getting a.txt and b.txt. Stranger still to me, if I put a.txt into another subfolder:

```
TestRecurse
 |---b.txt
 |---dir1
 |------dir2
 |---------a.txt
```

The same statement above only returns a.txt. I'm baffled as to how messing with the location of a.txt changes when b.txt is returned. Can someone explain to me why this happens, and why b.txt is ever returned at all?

***Update***

I should mention, while they're appreciated, I'm not necessarily looking for a workaround.  This is part of a larger script in our environment that is in charge of moving files around in various ways while trying stay flexible. It's not behaving as I expected it would, so I'm trying to understand why it's working the way it is. As pointed out by PetSerAl, understanding Get-ChildItem may be more trouble than it's worth.

Thanks!

Comment: Free tip: do not try to understand how `Get-ChildItem` work. The was many attempts to make its behavior user-friendlier, but in the result its behavior became more weird with each iteration, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You're including a wildcard for the parent directory (`TestRecurse\*`), so you are getting files contained in it as well. Try getting the folder list of the `TestRecurse`, then iterating through them.

Structure:

```
TestRecurse\b.txt
TestRecurse\dir1
TestRecurse\dir1\a.txt
```

Code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\tmp\TestRecurse\' | `    # Get the list of items within TestRecurse
   ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | `                # Filter items that are folders
   % {Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse}  # Iterate through and get all items within those folders
```

This only returns folders and files within dir1, but not dir1 itself.

Comment: So does gci effectively ignore the final \ in the path? Part of my confusion is that this occurs only when I specify Recurse.